# Angular js $setViewValue doesnt effect the ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I dont understand why the expression updated and the ng model value dont when im calling to $setViewValue function.

this is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2xdsujEsqDVVXaSPNqYE?p=preview

the code:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" set-value>
    {{user.name}}
    <input type="button" value="click" ng-click="change()">
  </body>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {name:'name'};
})
.directive('setValue', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,ele, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.change = function() {
        ctrl.$setViewValue('text');
      }

    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `ctrl.$render()` right after you do `ctrl.$setViewValue('text')`.  This will cause the UI to be updated with the latest model change.